# How to fix ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) in python

Tags: python

How to fix ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) in python

This is opencv project for motion detection using python By @dhruvmarathe

Having this problem from soo many days please help me solve this

**This is my code**

```
import cv2  
import time 

first_frame = None

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

        check, frame = video.read()
        print(frame)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21), 0)

        if first_frame is None:
           first_frame = gray
           continue

        delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame, gray)
        thresh_delta = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30 , 255 , cv2.THRESH_BINARY) [1]
        thresh_delta = cv2.dilate(thresh_delta, None, iterations=0 )
        (_,cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                                                    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for contour in cnts:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 1000:
                continue

            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 3)
        
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.imshow('Capturing',gray)
        cv2.imshow('delta', delta_frame)
        cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh_delta)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if key == ord('q'):
            break
        
        video.release()
```

Comment: in which line you got error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(_,cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                                                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) returns a tuple of two objects (contours and hierachy). You are trying to unpack three values (even if you discard the first and third).

I imagine from the name you've used, you want

```
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_delta.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                                                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Sir can you please check are there any more errors Please

Comment: No. I have never used cv2.

Comment: another error Please Help , ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()